# AWS Cloudfoundation select redhat linux AMI

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I am using this template to create my EC2 instance.  By default it installs Amazon Linux, how can I change this template to use  REHEL 7.4 OS?

https://s3-us-east-2.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-templates-us-east-2/WordPress_Single_Instance.template

Thanks
SR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to update the mapping with this AMI for Redhat Linux 7.4

```
 "us-east-2"      : { "HVM64" : "ami-cfdafaaa" },
```